# No se visualiza button en angular

Tags: angular

no he podido con este problema esto haciendo algo muy sencillo y me ha costado ya que dibujo un button en angular pero no se pinta en la visualización, el problema es que no me genera un mensaje de error por la consola.

[image: no se ve el boton generado]

Aqui esta mi código para que alguien por favor me diga en que estoy fallando

este es el componente.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-facturacion',
    templateUrl: './facturacion.component.html',
    providers: [MessageService],
    styleUrls: ['./facturacion.component.scss']
})
export class FacturacionComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

}
```

este es mi appModule.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { CookieModule } from 'ngx-cookie';
import { DividerModule } from 'primeng/divider';
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/button';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    SharedModule,
    DividerModule,
    ButtonModule,
    CookieModule.forRoot()
],
declarations: [
    AppComponent
],
providers: [
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Este es mi HTML

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="col-12 md:col-6">
        <div class="card">
            <h5>Default</h5>
            <button pButton pRipple label="Submit" class="mr-2 mb-2"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: pues el botón está vacío, no lleva nada adentro, porque no intentas escribiendo algo dentro de la etiqueta button?

Comment: mi hermano tiene toda la razon si fue solucionado aunque el problema de raiz es otro pero no me percate de que estaba vacio, creo que me toca abrir otro caso para el caso que le menciono, muchas gracias.